# Unit testing a facade class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, facade

I have a facade class, which implements the following method: `getTotalNumOfItems(Query query)`. The facade stands in front of two other service classes, which implement the same method. Depending on the type of the `query` parameter, the facade decides whether to delegate to one of the services or the other.

My dilemma is how to write a unit test for the facade, without the test having to know how the number of items is derived. Otherwise, it would look like an integration test, and not a unit test anymore.

I have provided in-place mock versions of the two services, using Mockito. However, when I write a unit test for this, the only thing I can test is "verify if the facade returns a number, equal to what one of the mocks returns (depending on query type)". There does not seem to have a way to test the facade in a way more agnostic than that.

Am I doing something wrong here? Should I be feeling worried? I guess, the nature of the facade is such that its efficiency can only be verified by getting to know the classes that it delegates to. Of course, I made sure to write unit tests for the same method, in both of the services.

Comment: You need to test individual service objects rather than facade itself.

Comment: So I did. Yet, I want to be sure that the facade always decides upon the right service to delegate to

Comment: No you should not else you are not doing UT. UT is just class and specific method.

Answer (score 6):

As you already said the responsibility of the facade is to decide to which service to delegate to. That is what you need to test. The return value of the service is of no interest for the test. So for your mocks just make sure in one test case one of those is called and the other is never invoked. And a second test case should test it's the other way round.